# add a line in the "n" position of a csv file that is being read

Tags: python

As I have searched, it does not seem to be so easy to read and edit at the same time in fact, I have not managed to achieve it. but what confuses me the most is how to add an element in a line "n" of my csv, for example I want to add a line in the line 2 of my `csv`.

> mycsv.csv

```
name,last name
yeison, smith
lola, boa
elmo, spitia
anderson, exneider
juan, ortega
```

my code:

```
with open("mycsv.csv", "r") as rfh:
 r = csv.DictReader(rfh)
 for idx, row in enumerate(r): #nothing happens
     print(r)    
 with open("mycsv.csv", "a") as wfh:
     if(idx==2):
        #append element "german,ezequiel"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading all lines then writing should work:

```
with open('mycsv.csv', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

lines.insert(2, 'german, ezequiel')

with open('mycsv.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write(''.join(lines))
```

Comment: thanks,it seems simpler than I thought, but what if I want to add more than one line at a time, for example in position 1, "pedro, picapiedra"?

Comment: You could insert multiple entries into the list `lines` by doing something like:
`lines = lines[:1] + ['pedro, picapiedra', 'german, ezequiel'] + lines[1:]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas`.

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv("mycsv.csv")

line = pd.DataFrame({"name": 'XYZ', "last name": 'ABC'}, index=[2])
df2 = pd.concat([df.ix[:1], line, df.ix[2:]]).reset_index(drop=True)

df2.to_csv("mycsv.csv", index=False)
```